# Can a standard PCIe card fit on top of VLP (Very Low Profile) memory?

Tags: memory, hardware, pci-express, workstation

I am dealing with a motherboard

https://b2b.gigabyte.com/Server-Motherboard/MZ31-AR0-rev-1x#ov

where multiple memory slots are situated right in front of several PCIe slots and hence a full-length PCIe card would not fit when populating the obstructing memory slots with full height memory.

Given that memory slots, memory heights, PCIE slots, and the height between the low end of the PCIe card and the motherboard is relatively standardized my question is as follows:

Would a VLP (Very Low Profile) memory module, inserted into a memory slot, still be low enough so that a full length PCIe card can still fit on top of such memory modules? I am obviously referring to workstation solutions or U4 server solutions where workstation/server boards are used and PCIe cards are inserted into the PCIe slots directly in vertical fashion.

I am considering above workstation/server motherboard (for EPYC CPU) where multiple PCIe slots are situated right in front of several memory slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By JEDEC spec, VLP DIMMs are up to 18.8 mm high (usually 18 mm).

The PCIe CEM 2.0 defines a vertical clearance of 16.15 mm.

Simple PCIe card will fit in between the DIMMs though (even standard size) - check the alignment. With bulky heatsinks or components near the edge it most probably won't fit.